# Scrollable page with listview

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquickcontrols2

I have a file named page2.qml like below

```
Page {
        id: page

        Rectangle {
            id: container
            anchors.fill: parent
            width: parent.width * 0.8

            Rectangle {
                id: title
                anchors.top: parent.top
                width: parent.width
                height: 50
                color: "salmon"
            }

            ListView {
                id: listView
                currentIndex: -1
                anchors.top: title.bottom
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom


                delegate: Rectangle {
                    height: 20
                    width: 100
                    border.color: "red"
                    color: "pink"
                    Text {
                        text: model.index
                    }
                }

                model: 100
            }
        }
    }
```

the result is in this image: 
[image: result]

Since the listview contain 100 item, how can i make the whole page scrollable? i can make just listview scrollable but not the whole page.

Comment: Make your `container` as [Flickable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html)

Comment: @PraveenKumar i wrap the container inside a `flickable`, and set `contentHeight: title.height + listView.contentHeight` and it works perfectly, thanks a lot.

Comment: @PraveenKumar please post your comment as an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: You got a better answer with example posted below:). Vote it up if it really helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the `ListView` to be scrollable by itself but your whole container need to, you could use a `Repeater` instead and put it inside a `Column` wrapped in a `Flickable` :

```
Flickable {
    id: container
    contentHeight: column.implicitHeight
    contentWidth: width
    width: parent.width * 0.8
    height: parent.height

    Column {
        id: column
        width: parent.width

        Rectangle {
            id: title
            width: parent.width
            height: 50
            color: "salmon"
        }

        Repeater {
            id: listView
            model: 100

            delegate: Rectangle {
                height: 20
                width: 100
                border.color: "red"
                color: "pink"
                Text {
                    text: model.index
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```